# Can you enter the Schengen area with a residency visa from another country?

Tags: schengen

The Schengen area has an Annex II list of countries, which grants passport holders the right to enter the Schengen area visa free. In addition, this right is present for citizens of non-Schengen members of the EU (Ireland, Romania, Croatia, Bulgaria). Does this right also extend to any *residents* of these countries?

In other words, is there a residency permit issued by any non-Schengen state that would enable its holder to enter the Schengen area visa free?

Definition of "residency permit/visa" for the purposes of this question: any identity document issued by a given nation to non-nationals who reside in its territory. I.e. an I-571 refugee document might not strictly speaking be a "residency permit" but lets consider it such for the purposes of a canonical answer.

> NB: this is intended as a canonical question to cover all possible variations of this question

Comment: I think it's unlikely. For non-Schengen EU states, even EU family members residing in those countries technically require a visa to visit Schengen (though if they are travelling or joining their EU family member, a visa is issued on the spot free of charge if they manage to reach the Schengen border, e.g. road or rail crossings, and prove the relationship).

Comment: I’m aware that US refugee document holders can enter Germany and a few other Schengen states so it’s possible there are exceptions.

Comment: If you accept territorially restricted visa-waivers within Schengen, then there are a few other exceptions in some countries IIRC, e.g. organized school trips for pupils resident of non-Schengen EU states.

Comment: Sure, a canonical answer should include all edge cases.

Comment: @xngtg that is incorrect.  Someone with a residence card issued under article 10 or article 20 of directive 2004/38/EC is explicitly exempted from the requirement to have a visa by article 5(2).

Comment: A US refugee document is not a "residence permit" as such.

Comment: @phoog thanks, updated question.

Comment: @phoog but only if they are traveling with or joining the EU-Spouse. When traveling alone they may require a visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson in my opinion, the directive is ambiguous on that question, but that is certainly the interpretation of immigration authorities.

Comment: @phoog **Practical Handbook for Border Guards**, Point 2.8, Page 22: *A Slovak citizen resides with his Chinese spouse in Ireland. The Chinese spouse holding a residence card, issued by Ireland under Article 20 of the Directive, travels alone to France. As she travels alone, she needs to apply for a visa to enter France.* Applies to Member states not yet fully applying the Schengen acquis;

Comment: @phoog I checked again and I think this is another case where the differences among Schengen states/EU states/bilateral treaties with Switzerland are a mess. For a Chinese EU family member in Croatia, Timatic shows visa required for Switzerland (I knew this because someone got denied boarding from Croatia) but for France it explicitly says Union citizen families are exempt.

Comment: @MarkJohnson as I said, I know that interpretation is broadly accepted, but a close reading of the directive shows that either the interpretation is incorrect or the directive is poorly drafted.

Comment: @xngtng Switzerland being a Schengen state, it cannot require a visa of a Chinese national who has an article 10 card from Croatia and who travels to Switzerland with, or to join, the EU citizen with whom he or she resides in Croatia.  If TIMATIC fails to recognize that, then either Switzerland is wrong or TIMATIC is wrong.  In the latter case, it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @phoog But that is then your **personal opinion**, so saying that xngtng statement is incorrect is a false statement. The **Practical Handbook for Border Guards** also states on the same page that Article 2(16)(a) of the Schengen Borders Code defines a *residence permit* as *all residence permits issued by the **Member States** according to the uniform format laid down by Council Regulation (EC) No 1030/2002 (1) and **residence cards issued in accordance with Directive 2004/38/EC**;*...

Comment: @phoog ...Ireland and Croatia are not Member States of the Schengen acquis, so their Article 19/20 resident cards are **not** considered residence permits, but only as proof that they are a family member of an EU Citizen and can cross an external border with or to join the EU-Spouse. Travelling alone, they require a visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson there are two different issues here.  My personal opinion concerns an unorthodox interpretation of the directive, which I fully accept is not shared by any border authority.  However, the statement by xngtng is incorrect even under the most restrictive and uncontroversial interpretation, for example a Romanian citizen and Chinese spouse, holding an Art. 10 card, traveling together from Croatia to Switzerland. In that case, a visa is *not* required, and no visa is issued at the border, contrary to the statement in xngtng's first comment, so that statement is, as I said, incorrect.

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I misread that part of xngtng comment. A visa, free of charge, will be issued at a consulate if the family member wants to travel alone. When traveling with the spouse they are allowed to enter without the need of a visa.

Answer (score 2):

No, since Ireland, Romania, Croatia, Bulgaria and Cyprus do not **fully** implement the *Schengen acquis* and are therefore not considered a **Contracting Party**.

The Schengen Border Code uses the term **Member States**, but doesn't define exactly what that means.

Article 2(16)(a) of the Schengen Borders Code defines a *residence permit* as

> all residence permits issued by the **Member States** according to the uniform format laid down by Council Regulation (EC) No 1030/2002 (1) and **residence cards issued in accordance with Directive 2004/38/EC**;

The **Practical Handbook for Border Guards**, Point 2.8, Page 22 gives samples when a visa is needed or not.

> A Slovak citizen resides with his Chinese spouse in Ireland. The Chinese spouse holding a residence card, issued by Ireland under Article 20 of the Directive, travels alone to France.
> As she travels alone, she needs to apply for a visa to enter France.

Article 19/20 resident cards, that are not issued by **Member States** [of the Schengen acquis] are **not** considered residence permits, but only as proof that they are a family member of an EU Citizen and can cross an external border with or to join the EU-Spouse. Travelling alone, they require a visa.

Since family members of EU-Citizens may require a Schengen Visa, when they reside in a non-Schengen EU Member state, to enter the Schengen Area, one can assume that **Member States of the Schengen acquis**. is meant.

---

Article 21(1) of the [The Schengen acquis - Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement of 14 June 1985...](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX%3A42000A0922%2802%29%3AEN%3AHTML): *Aliens who hold valid residence permits issued by one of the **Contracting Parties** may, on the basis of that permit and a valid travel document, move freely for up to three months within the territories of the other Contracting Parties, provided that they fulfil the entry conditions referred to in Article 5(1)(a), (c) and (e) and are not on the national list of alerts of the Contracting Party concerned.*

---

**Sources**:

- [Practical Handbook for Border Guards - European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/default/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/c2019-7131-annex.pdf) PDF